# How to click a button with puppeteer using the id

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I want to click a button on a webpage using puppeteer. I have this button tag with a specific id (qa-guest-checkout)

```html
<button id="qa-guest-checkout" aria-label="Checkout here" class="ncss-btn-accent u-rounded u-full-width ncss-brand u-uppercase pt3-sm pt2-lg pr5-sm pb3-sm pb2-lg pl5-sm fs14-sm d-lg-h"><span class="d-sm-ib va-sm-m mr1-sm">Checkout here</span></button>
```

But now if i select the button via the id, i get an undefined error. See below my code snippet.

```js
    await page.waitForSelector('button[id=qa-guest-checkout]');
        await page.evaluate(() =>
        document.querySelectorAll('button[id=qa-guest-checkout]')[0].scrollIntoView()
    );
    await page.evaluate(() =>
        document.querySelectorAll('button[id=qa-guest-checkout]')[0].click()
    );
```

Do i have to select the button in a different way? Is there another way to select this button with puppeteer?

Comment: Make the string `'button[id="qa-guest-checkout"]'` (or with escaped single quotes). Then it should work. Example: `document.querySelectorAll('button[id="qa-guest-checkout"]')[0]`

Comment: still undefined error: `(node:8164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined`

Comment: Hmmm, that's a bit weird. Try this: `document.querySelectorAll('button#qa-guest-checkout')`

Comment: @serious_speaker If you need to scroll it into view, please show a [mcve] that includes the markup (or live URL) that gives enough context to motivate the scroll you show in your code.